# Undefined index, jQuery var to php var with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Aloha everyone out there! I've been searching around for hours, trying all different kind of $.ajax setups and all that.

But all i can get is an "Undefined index" error.
At the moment, im using this while trying to pass the var from my script.js, 
to conInfo.php

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'conInfo.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: {'data': 1},
 success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
 }
});
```

And inside of my conInfo.php

```
<?php
 $value = $_POST['data'];
 echo $value;
?>
```

And this site is required within my index.php, with the connected script.js
Thanks partypeople.

Comment: The code you've shown won't cause that error. If you click the error in the console it should take you to the offending line of code.

Comment: Yeah I know, but somehow i get a undefined index.
Gonna read up about it.

Comment: One good debugging technique is to see how the code is being rendered in the html by looking at the pages source and seeing if it matches up with what you think should be there. Usually a variable is coming in wrong or something. You can right click on your webpage and select "View page source", then find (Ctrl+F) the code you're looking for.